# Cannot create new record through ACCESS form

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

BACK END - SQL Server

FRONT END - Access 2010 (2000 format)

The system stores and retrieves data about technical documents.  Broadly, there are three tables A, B and C, each of which maintains data about a different type of document.

The ACCESS front end provides a Search Form and Data Entry/Edit form (bound to the underlying table) for each document type.  In all three document types, when adding a new record, the user will open the Search form and press a button called "Add".  This opens the Data Entry/Edit form and in the Form_Load event is the line

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

When the data entry is complete, the user presses a "Close" button which simply runs the code

```
DoCmd.Close
```

As I said, the design and code of the objects relating to the three document types is, for all intents and purposes, identical.  However, while for tables A and B the process of adding a new record is seamless and extremely quick, for table C it has proved impossible to add a new record via the ACCESS UI.  The edit form will open correctly to add the data, but when the user presses the "Close" button the form hangs, and eventually returns to the Search form without the new record having been added.

It is possible to bypass the UI by opening ACCESS while holding down the SHIFT key, opening the linked table, and adding new records directly.  While this is acceptable as an interim measure, it is unacceptable in the long term.  It should be noted that the system is about ten years old, and has been working entirely correctly for about nine of those years (apart from minor glitches moving between different versions of ACCESS).

Unfortunately this system is owned and operated by a major global corporation and it is very difficult for me, a subcontracted supplier, to get access to the SQL Server box to run diagnosis (SQL Profiler would be a good starting point).  My gut feeling is that there is a subtle difference in the permissions model for that particular table but I don't know.

The situation is further complicated by the fact that I have a copy of the system at my work and I cannot reproduce the problem.  Of course, there are bound to be subtle differences between the two architectures (for example, I don't know for certain what version of SQL Server it's running on, but I believe it's 2000, nor do I know how completely it is patched or updated) but the facts are that for one particular table bound to one particular form, it is not possible to add records, whereas for other tables there is no such problem.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas about how to go about diagnosing this or even solving it (if anyone has come across the same problem before).

Many thanks

Edward

Comment: Edward, why is it difficult to get access to the SQL Server? Is there no possibility to use a remote session to get access to the server. If they want you to solve the problem, they need to help you out somehow??

Comment: Hi Jaques - there are security considerations to do with MOD and US Defense Dept which restrict access (I've asked for remote access many times, but there is no chance), not to mention the most obstructive and difficult DBA I've ever come across!

Comment: Could you make the form unbound and then add the record via an 'INSERT' statement in code, triggered by the Close button? (Disregard my "answer", it was meant as a comment!)

Comment: Hi Matt - yes, I could do that; however, my inner OCD really wants to understand why this particular situation obtains.  I've run it past the only other extant Access maven at my company, and he's equally mystified, though he did suggest that there may be a problem in that there is a disparity between the company's dataset and mine (I took a snapshot of their data some time ago, which should be identical schematically but will be assuredly different informationally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule when you encounter problems to update a table, then this tends to suggests that the table does not have a PK or the form the query is based on does not have a PK exposed.

The next thing I would ensure is the table has a time stamp column as Access uses this to test for record changes behind the scenes.

Next up I would check the default locking for the form (while these settings generally don't effect odbc, they should be checked).

Next up is to check if the table has any "bit" column (true/false) and ensure that the defaults for such controls are set SQL SERVER side (they should default to 0). This null bits issue will cause updates to fail if not addressed.

I would also check if the form in question is based on a query or if the data source is set directly to the table. As noted the PK auto number ID of that table in query should be  INTEGER value sql side – big int is NOT supported.

So check default values (both in sql table and on the form (those controls) to ensure nothing be set that would prevent the update.

Comment: Thank you Albert for your usual learned answer.  I can confirm that there is a PK, that it is an integer.  The form is bound to a table, not a query.  There is a bit column that is not defaulted and there is no timestamp column.  However, my instinct is that these are not the cause of the problem because a) the system worked correctly for about 8 years with the current design and b) it works correctly on my network with these "faults". Nevertheless, I will address these issues and revert if the problem is not sorted.